# Are Lucifer and Satan different beings?

Tags: satan

I have heard an interview where a Jesuit exorcist said that Lucifer and Satan were different beings. I'd always thought that they were the same.

- Are both Lucifer and Satan mentioned by name in the Bible?
- What is the support for considering them the same being? What is the support for considering them separate beings?

Comment: You then agreed with the exorcist? (The way you've phrased that makes me think you might have messed something up there... just want to make sure.)

Comment: No not necessarily, I'd just always assumed that they were referring to the same person. However, I realized it was in fact an assumption, I'd never found biblical evidence this is the fact, so that is why I ask the question.

Comment: ^ you said you thought they were different, check your question.

Comment: They are different. There are 7 Princes of hell Satan is 1 and Lucifer is another. Look up the [7 princes of hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_princes_of_Hell) (Wikipedia) and read about it.

Comment: *Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/bishops-have-no-free-will) for the logic behind my response.* Your question should be down voted for "lack of research with some other translations first" - **per Wikis**.  "A) Use a Bible in a language you speak and B) use a dictionary. Either or both of those things would save you from this sort of misunderstanding." - **per Caleb**.  Lucifer isn't the devil or Satan.

Comment: @thefreemason your comment doesn't make any sense? You are saying had I used the dictionary, or a bible in my language, I would have just realized that Lucifer isn't the devil or satan? From wikipedia: "Later Christian tradition came to use the Latin word for "morning star", lucifer, as a proper name ("Lucifer") for Satan as he was before his fall"... so a quick google has already produced confusion on this topic. Seems like a valid question.

Comment: Using the logic behind my down voted question, the King James Bible is not English - that is, not how we use English today.  Using a different version of the bible, you will not find Lucifer anywhere in it.  Using a dictionary for the word lucifer and it's origin would answer your question.  It would require research on your part, however.  The Christian use of Lucifer comes from a mistranslation, a similar misunderstanding put horns on statues of Moses.

Comment: @TheFreemason The type of question and research that would be applicable is quite different from the one you ripped my quote out of context from. I'd appreciate being allowed to speak for myself, and I'd imagine Wikis feels the same. If I see an issue let me make my own comments. If you see an issue make your own comments. In this case I think you are trying to pigeon-hole a conclusion and you missed the fact that the premises and context are incompatable with the argument you stole.

Comment: @caleb I do not see how this is a different argument. I quoted, not stole, giving credit to you - the proper thing to do.  My following comment further solidifies your wonderful comment.  Continue the good work, my brother in Christ!

Answer (score 12):

The name "Lucifer" appears only once in the Bible, in [Isaiah](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014:12&version=KJV) (KJV), where he alludes to the tale (which we can assume is already known to his Jewish audience at that time) of the great Lucifer having fallen from heaven, being cast down and looked upon with contempt, in order to draw a parallel to the king of Babylon and his kingdom's impending fall.

Lucifer means "morning star", which is used various times and in various ways in the Bible, including by Christ to refer to *himself* at one point in Revelation.  But see [Job 38 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+38&version=RSVCE), where it says that when the foundations of the world were laid, "the morning stars sang together, and all the sons of God shouted for joy."  I think this is the closest we have in the Bible to a passage equating Lucifer with an angel.

It's important to note that both of these passages are highly poetic in nature, as is the third, the story of the [Dragon in Revelation](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:3-7&version=KJV), who is cast out of heaven and makes war with the Church, who is equated to Satan.  If the dragon cast out of heaven is the same as Lucifer the Morning Star cast out of heaven, then he is Satan.  But it's difficult to say anything for certain, going only on Biblical authority.

Comment: Can you provide specific references to Luciver in Isaiah, and the dragon in revelation?

Comment: The word "lucifer" doesn't appear in the Bible *at all* in its original languages. It is a Latin word, and the Old Testament is written in Hebrew and the New Testament is written in Greek. No angel is given a Latin name, only Hebrew (eg, Michael and Gabriel). Lucifer doesn't mean "morning star", it means "light-bearer". It has a Greek counterpart, "phosphoros", which is actually used once in the NT in 2 Peter 1:19. I provide more detail in my answer at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/how-do-we-know-that-satan-lucifer-and-devil-are-the-same-guy/24796#24796.

Answer (score 5):

Lucifer is a transliteration of the name Morningstar used in the Latin Vulgate. Satan was referred to the Morningstar several times in the Bible. [Wikipedia has a good explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer#Use_of_the_word_.22lucifer.22_in_the_Bible) of where the these terms are used in the Bible and what the various contexts are.

We know that the being who is Satan was one of the chief angels who decided he would rather have the glory for himself that God had reserved as His own.

While the exorcist may have met demons with various names, we know demons are primarily invested in lying, and so I would take what the exorcist claimed with a grain of salt.

Comment: The only points I'd add is Wikipedia's entry on lucifer is seriously flawed; for one thing, lacking information on the office of "light-bearer" which is what lucifer actually means. I go into more detail in my answer on http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/how-do-we-know-that-satan-lucifer-and-devil-are-the-same-guy/24796#24796. Also, the OP didn't write that the exorcist said demons told him satan and lucifer were different beings.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but since there was no selected answer, I thought I'd give it a go. The answer is going to depend a lot on the denomination that is answering, so I will approach this from a purely non-biased, non-denominated, purely Scriptural point of view.

Now, are Lucifer and Satan the same being? **Yes and no.**

As an adjective, the Latin word **lucifer** means **"light-bringing"** and was applied to the moon. As a noun, it meant **"morning star"**, or in poetry, **"day"**. This word, being Latin, actually should not exist in English translations, and should actually be translated into one of the above options. This word is a Latin translation of הֵילֵל, read as hêlêl or heylel.

**Isaiah 14:12** is not the only place where the Vulgate uses the word "lucifer". It uses the **same word four more times**, in contexts where it clearly has **no reference to a fallen angel**: **2 Peter 1:19** (meaning "morning star"), **Job 11:17** ("the light of the morning"), **Job 38:32** ("the signs of the zodiac") and **Psalms 110:3** ("the dawn"). To speak of the "morning star", lucifer is not the only expression that the Vulgate uses: three times it uses *stella matutina*: Sirach 50:6 (**referring** to the **actual** morning star), and Revelation 2:28 (though this might actually use the word "lucifer" or "lux ferre") and 22:16 (**referring to Jesus**).

Another fun little note is that the [Exsultet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsultet) includes "lucifer" in clear description of Jesus Christ. Use of "Lucifer" as a names popularized by Dante Alighieri's *Inferno* and John Milton's *Paradise Lost*.

In regards to Isaiah 14:12, translating the actual line gives us "Hillel ben-Shahar", which very well could have been the name of Babylon's King, being that Hebrew contains no indications for capitalization.

Now for **Satan**:

Satan comes from the Hebrew word שָּׂטָן (**pronounced "satan"**), meaning **"adversary", "accuser", or "enemy"**. The original Hebrew term is a noun/verb meaning **“obstruct, oppose,”**. It is **almost always accompanied by the prefix "ha-"** in Hebrew, meaning **"the"** in English - thus **"the adversary", "the accuser", etc.**

So back to the question, **are Lucifer and Satan the different beings?**

**Yes and no.**

Lucifer, whether Isaiah was writing about the Devil or not, was **clearly an enemy of God and His people** - so he would have been "ha-Satan", **the enemy**. If Lucifer is in fact the Devil, he is both the enemy by the Hebrew definition and Satan as we know him.

Answer (score 2):

**Q.** "***Are Lucifer and Satan different beings?***"

**A.** Satan filled **the king of Babylon** with the ambition to have complete domination over the earth, even over “Jehovah’s throne” (1Ch 29:23) and “**the stars of God**,” the kings of the line of David sitting on the throne at Mount Moriah (by extension, Zion).

This “**king**,” that is, **the dynasty of Babylon**, ‘lifted himself up’ in his own heart and was in his own eyes and in the eyes of his admirers a “**shining one**,” a “**son of the dawn**.” (In *some* Bible translations the **Latin Vulgate** term “**Lucifer**” is retained. It is, however, merely *the translation* of the Hebrew word **heh·lel′**, “**shining one**.” Heh·lel′ **is not a name or a title** but, rather, **a term** *describing the boastful position taken by Babylon’s dynasty of kings of the line of Nebuchadnezzar*.) (Isa 14:4-21) Since Babylon was a tool of Satan, **its “king” reflected Satan’s own ambitious desire**.

NOTE: This answer represents the Jehovah's Witnesses perspective.