# What is the Biblical basis for saying Lucifer is an angel?

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, angels

Where in the Bible does it say that Lucifer was one of the angels or an archangel?

Comment: Where in the Bible does it say his name was Lucifer?

Comment: @Dan: [Isaiah 14:12 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+14:12&version=KJV).

Comment: @Wikis The Hebrew text has הֵילֵל בֶּן־שָׁחַר (helel ben-shakhar, “Helel son of Shachar”), which is probably a name for the morning star (Venus) or the crescent moon. ["Lucifer" actually comes from the Latin Vulgate text.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer) My point was merely to highlight assumptions inherent in the question.

Comment: @Dan: sure, but I thought your question was literally looking for chapter / verse in the Bible.

Comment: The verses in this context, "which appear to be spoken by other pagan kings to a pagan king (cf. vv. 9-11), contain several titles and motifs that resemble those of Canaanite mythology, including references to Helel son of Shachar, the stars of El, the mountain of assembly, the recesses of Zaphon, and the divine title Most High. Apparently these verses allude to a mythological story about a minor god (Helel son of Shachar) who tried to take over Zaphon, the mountain of the gods. His attempted coup failed and he was hurled down to the underworld.

Comment: "The king of Babylon is taunted for having similar unrealized delusions of grandeur. Some Christians have seen an allusion to the fall of Satan here, but this seems contextually unwarranted (see J. Martin, “Isaiah,” *BKCOT*, 1061)." (cf. [NET translator's note](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Isaiah+14:12)).

Comment: @Wikis no problem. I should have clarified my intention with that question - I was well aware of the passage.

Comment: @Dan - "My point was merely to highlight assumptions inherent in the question" - Where in my question did I make an assumption that "Lucifer" is a name?

Comment: @Dan: maybe make this into a new question and answer?

Comment: @brilliant the question itself uses the term (whether as a title or a name) - anyways it's not important. It's a good question - I was just trying to stimulate thought on the translation choice. I didn't realize it would turn into this. My apologies. I probably should have put a wink ;) after the question.

Comment: Satan would have been an angel. Archangel is not used in plural in Greek so there is only 1. This is an excellent question btw

Comment: *Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/bishops-have-no-free-will) for the logic behind my response.* Your question should be down voted for "lack of research with some other translations first" - **per Wikis**.  "A) Use a Bible in a language you speak and B) use a dictionary. Either or both of those things would save you from this sort of misunderstanding." - **per Caleb**.  Lucifer isn't the devil or Satan.

Comment: The Hebrew word translated “Lucifer” means “shining one.” The Septuagint uses the Greek word that means “bringer of dawn.” Hence, some translations render the original Hebrew “morning star” or “Daystar.” But Jerome’s Latin Vulgate uses “Lucifer” (light bearer), and this accounts for the appearance of that term in various versions of the Bible.

Comment: The expression “shining one,” or “Lucifer,” is found in what Isaiah prophetically commanded the Israelites to pronounce as a “proverbial saying against the king of Babylon.”That the description “shining one” is given to a man and not to a spirit creature is  seen by the statement: “Down to Sheol you will be brought.” Sheol is the common grave of mankind—not a place occupied by Satan the Devil. Moreover, those seeing Lucifer brought into this condition ask: “Is this the man that was agitating the earth?” Clearly, “Lucifer” refers to a human, not to a spirit creature.—Isaiah 14:4, 15, 16.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-lucifer-and-satan-different-beings.    Related question closed why was this one left open?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interesting question. In the Bible, this is strongly hinted at rather than directly stated. Here is the evidence:

In [Job 1:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+1:6&version=NIV1984) we learn that **Satan was in heaven with other angels**.

> One day the angels came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan also came with them.

That Satan is (was) in heaven is also seen in [Zechariah 3:1-2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zechariah%203:1-2&version=NIV1984), [Luke 10:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2010:18&version=NIV1984) and [Revelation 12:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:9&version=NIV1984). Revelation 12:9 gives a further clue to Satan's identity:

> The great dragon was hurled down—that ancient serpent called the devil, or Satan, who leads the whole world astray. He was hurled to the earth, and **his angels with him**.

This thought is also stated by Jesus in [Matthew 25:41](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025:41&version=NIV1984):

> “Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart from me, you who are cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for **the devil and his angels**.

That he has his own angels, is a further clue to him being a (former) angel. (And incidentally, [Isaiah 14:12-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014:12-15&version=NIV1984) is often used to show *why* Satan fell, because he wanted to ascend to God's throne).

Note also [2 Corinthians 11:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%2011:14&version=NIV1984), which says that Satan can *"masquerade as an angel of light."*

**Conclusion:** we know that Satan lives / has lived in heaven, with other angels (some of which are his own), that he was (or will be) cast out of heaven. From this we infer that he is a *"fallen angel"*.

**Update:** In my answer above I assembled evidence for Satan being an angel. But it's not **proof** *(see comments below)*. Which leads me to consider [proof by exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion): if Satan was *not* an angel, what could he be? I know of only three types of sentient beings in the Bible: God, man and angels. He's clearly *not* God, nor man. That only leaves one other option.

**Update on *Lucifer*:** @Dan asks where Lucifer is named as such. The answer is in [Isaiah 14:12 KJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+14:12&version=KJV):

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!

This verse and the wider passage are historically interpreted as referring to Satan, though it is not directly stated.

<sub>Footnote: there are only two *named* angels in the Bible. **Michael** ([Daniel 10:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010:13&version=NIV1984), [Daniel 10:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2010:21&version=NIV1984), [Daniel 12:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%2012:1&version=NIV1984), [Jude 1:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jude%201:9&version=NIV1984) & [Revelation 12:7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:7&version=NIV1984)) & **Gabriel** ([Daniel 8:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%208:16&version=NIV1984), [Daniel 9:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%209:21&version=NIV1984), [Luke 1:19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201:19&version=NIV1984) & [Luke 1:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201:26&version=NIV1984)).</sub>

Comment: Wikipedia has an interesting article, [Christian teaching about the Devil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_teaching_about_the_Devil) which contains *more* information (I did not use this for my answer).

Comment: The Catholics and Orthodox also have Tobit as a canonical book, which features the angel Raphael.

Comment: Thank you again for all these verses, but again I feel we have a missing link here. I mean logically we can't yet jump from "Jack with his soldiers" or "Jack among his soldiers" to the conclusion that Jack is also a soldier. Do you understand what I mean? Otherwise, we could also conclude that Jesus is an angel from "...when the Lord Jesus shall be revealed from heaven with his mighty angels" (2 Th 1:7) or a saint from "...the Lord comes with ten thousands of His saints" (Jude 1:14). Yes, you are right: it is hinted, but not directly stated, so I think we need to find some logical basis for

Comment: that (I mean some logical sequence proving that Satan is merely an angel (or the highest of all angels), yet not like the Son of God). At the moment I am reading the material from Wikipedia that you have referred me to.

Comment: @brilliant: true. However, we can easily conclude that **Jesus** is not an angel from other passages, particularly [Hebrews 1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=hebrews%201&version=NIV)

Comment: @Wikis - WOW!!! Wikis, I just don't know how come I never thought of that! Exactly! Both me and my brother belong to the same kind as we both were born from the same father who is a human. My father couldn't have given a birth to a human and to a reptile. This logical argument is so simple and yet it is so strong! It's just genius! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Wikis - Well, Wikis, I just had a second thought about this argument of yours and kind of brought myself "back to the earth". I mean, the evidence that you brought up from Hebrews is a strong proof that Jesus is not an angel, however it doesn't prove that Lucifer is an angel. I think we still need some more logical constructions here in order to prove that.

Comment: @brilliant, yes that is correct. I was trying to say that, in Jesus' case, there is more evidence. In Satan's case, I don't think there is more. Apparently God does not wish to dwell on him in His book! :)

Comment: @Wikis: God, archangels, angels, and man?

Comment: @DanAndrews: oh, I see, you're saying that archangels are different from angels? Sounds like a good candidate for a new question... :)

Comment: @AffableGeek: of course, to make it into a complete summary we'd need to add other aspects of his character, eg verses that confirm his [demonic nature](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2022:3&version=AMP).

Comment: Ok so every time someone asks where the bible talks about Lucifer, we get a slew of references to satan. So I would ask this: where does the bible ever imply that lucifer and satan are referring to the same thing let alone a person? The only mention of lucifer I've seen is in Isiah and that is a narrative and used as a descriptive noun, not a proper noun. The same could be said about the word satan.

Comment: *Please see [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31389/bishops-have-no-free-will) for the logic behind my response.* Your question should be down voted for "lack of research with some other translations first" - **per Wikis**.  "A) Use a Bible in a language you speak and B) use a dictionary. Either or both of those things would save you from this sort of misunderstanding." - **per Caleb**.  Lucifer isn't the devil or Satan.

Comment: @TheFreemason: thank you for explaining your downvote. Indeed, I did make that mistake in the original draft of my question (assuming Lucifer = Satan) but then I added an update to explain it. That wasn't the core of *this* question, though, but of *[this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-lucifer-and-satan-different-beings?rq=1)*.

Answer (score 8):

"Where in the Bible does it say that Lucifer was one of the angels or an archangel?"

It doesn't.

“Lucifer” is actually a Hebrew *word* when translated means “shining one.” The Septuagint uses the Greek word that means “bringer of dawn.” That is why some translations render the original Hebrew “morning star” or “Daystar.” But Jerome’s Latin Vulgate uses “Lucifer” (light bearer), and this accounts for the appearance of that term in various versions of the Bible.

The 'name' Lucifer occurs once in the Scriptures (Isa. 14:12) and only in some versions of the Bible. Traditionally, Lucifer is a name that in English generally refers to the Devil before being cast from heaven. But this description is given to a man and not to a spirit creature as is further seen by the statement: “Down to Sheol you will be brought.” Sheol is the common grave of mankind—not a place occupied by Satan the Devil. Additionally, those seeing Lucifer brought into this condition ask: “Is this the MAN that was agitating the earth?” Clearly, “Lucifer” refers to a human, not to a spirit creature. - Isaiah 14:4, 15, 16.

Careful Exegesis has actually conclude that Isaiah did not have Satan in mind when he says "Lucifer," but actually the king of Babylon.

CONCERNING THE TRADITION OF LUCIFER BEING A NAME FOR THE DEVIL

I have read that before the rise of Christianity, it was the pseudepigrapha of Enochic Judaism who interpreted Isaiah 14:12-15 as applicable to Satan, and presented him as a fallen angel cast out of Heaven. Christian tradition, influenced by this presentation, came to use the Latin word for "morning star", lucifer, as a proper name ("Lucifer") for Satan as he was before his fall. As a result, "Lucifer has become a by-word for Satan in the Church and in popular literature", as in Dante Alighieri's Inferno and John Milton's Paradise Lost.

You may appreciate the following link to further information: [SHINING ONE](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200275280) (Isaiah 14:12).

Comment: The word *lucifer* is Latin. No doubt about it.

Comment: _Lucifer_ isn't a Hebrew word, it's Latin. Although you are correct it means _light-bearer_. The Greek word for _light-bearer_ is used in 2 Pe 1:19 in reference to Jesus. I provide a more complete response on the question of lucifer in my answer http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/how-do-we-know-that-satan-lucifer-and-devil-are-the-same-guy/24796#24796, including the fact that the Early Christians didn't consider lucifer to be the name of the angel before his disobedience.

Answer (score 6):

Many commentators use the scripture in [Ezekiel 28:11-17](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+28/) to represent, symbolically, the angel called Lucifer or Satan who was involved with worship and was in the garden and was also among the fiery stones. (See Moses on the mountain for this reference.) All of the allusions in Ezekiel seem to say that the person/angel referred to was the devil/Satan/Lucifer. The most obvious interpretation of the scripture is that it is really about the King of Tyre but as in any scripture there is sometimes an immediate interpretation and a future completion.

If you look at the example in [Isaiah 9:6](http://www.esvbible.org/Isaiah+9/)  about Jesus and the  reference to a "virgin birth," God speaks prophetically, "Behold a virgin shall bring forth a child." Most historians have said this refers to another event that happened within the life of the prophet; having said this, many of the gospel writers and early church writers have understood this as a direct prophetic word for the virgin birth of Jesus Christ. So the answer to the Question in "Where in the Bible does it refer to Lucifer?" could refer to the story of the King Tyre and the allusions to an angel in the garden of Eden and a perfectly created being that fell because of sin and worship of his own beauty in Ezekiel. There many allusions to Lucifer in Ezekiel in chapters [25](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+25), [28](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+28), [29](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+29), [35](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+35) and [39](http://www.esvbible.org/Ezekiel+39) as well.

Comment: Welcome to [Christianity.SE], Paul.  That's a fine answer.  Can you point to an example commentator or two who suggest this view?  That would take this answer to another level.  ;-)  (But +1 in any case.)

Answer (score 2):

You view is absolutely incorrect.  There are more than 3 typs of beings.  Look up the [Cherubim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherub).  The bible talks about different beings.

> The Hebrew term cherubim is cognate with the Assyrian term karabu, Akkadian term kuribu, and Babylonian term karabu; the Assyrian term means 'great, mighty', but the Akkadian and Babylonian cognates mean 'propitious, blessed'.[3][4] In some regions the Assyro-Babylonian term came to refer in particular to spirits which served the gods, in particular to the shedu (human-headed winged bulls);[4] the Assyrians sometimes referred to these as kirubu, a term grammatically related to karabu.[3] They were originally a version of the shedu, protective deities sometimes found as pairs of colossal statues either side of objects to be protected, such as doorways.[4][5] However, although the shedu were popular in Mesopotamia, archaeological remains from the Levant suggest that they were quite rare in the immediate vicinity of the Israelites.[5] The related Lammasu (human-headed winged lions — to which the sphinx is similar in appearance), on the other hand, were the most popular winged-creature in Phoenician art, and so scholars suspect that Cherubim were originally a form of Lammasu.[5] In particular, in a scene reminiscent of Ezekiel's dream, the Megiddo Ivories — ivory carvings found at Megiddo (which became a major Israelite city) — depict an unknown king being carried on his throne by hybrid winged-creatures.[6]

The bible NEVER gives the impression of angelic beings being the ONLY ones in existence besides man, god and angels.  And in this instance Cherubims are not baby like beings, they are to be so big that a human can walk under them or even ride them as they fly.

Comment: where is the quote from? What are all the footnotes? Ah wikipedia corrected. Please don't quote without citing your source.

Comment: Hello, Nelson, and welcome to the site. It seems that you are actually responding to an answer rather than answering the question. Also, I see you put the large middle section in quotes; if that is from another source please give us a link or the title of the book. You can edit this or delete it with the links below it. FYI: There are also Seraphim in Isiah and the 24 Elders in Revelation, etc. There are quite a few examples of non-angel, non-human sentient creatures. Also, angel may not be a species at all, but an office of position.

Comment: If a cheribum is a kind of angel, then the three kinds of beings framework works.

Answer (score 2):

Freds Bend put it the best way I have ever heard.

> Also, angel may not be a species at all, but an office of position.

It is true it never talks about Satan BEING an angel.... BUT! The bible also states the "powers and the principalities"

Ephesians 6:12

For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.

Evil can still be in the heavenly realms and FORCES is indeed plural...So I would take that and automatically think that angels are not the only things that turned evil. Correct?