# If Satan is not a fallen angel, created by God, then where did he come from? How was he created?

Tags: lds, satan

If Satan is not a fallen angel, created by God, then where did he come from? How was he created?

LDS theology holds that Satan and Jesus were both spirit children of Heavenly Father.  If traditional Christianity claims Mormonism is wrong on this topic, then where did Satan come from? Where do angels in general come from?

Comment: This question is way too speculative. It seems to ask what would be true if neither LDS beliefs nor beliefs consistent with the Nicene creed were correct.

Comment: The specific difference is that traditional Christianity says the satan came into existence, whereas Jesus always existed (i.e. the satan is a creature, whereas Jesus is *the* creator). In Mormonism, *both* the satan and Jesus came into existence; they are both creatures.

Comment: Why do you think that traditional Christianity says Satan is not a fallen angel?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  However, it seems you've mistaken the purpose of this site, asking one speculative question after another.,.  I hope you choose to participate further, but before you do, you should read [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and then [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and
[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 4):

> "*If traditional Christianity claims Mormonism is wrong on this topic, then where did Satan come from? Where do angels in general come from?*"

Traditional Christianity claims that Satan was created by God, as were all angels, as was everything.

> - **John 1:1-3 ESV**  In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was in the beginning with God. *All things were made through him, **and without him was not any thing made that was made.***

And we believe that Satan IS a fallen angel. You can check out this thorough answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2612/11471

Answer (score 0):

This URL (http://www.gotquestions.org/Satan-fall.html) has a ton of information with Scripture references. I recommend going there to start your own research.

The Bible clearly states that Satan was one of God's most prestigious angels before he fell from Grace. He lost his eligibility for grace because he was prideful and wanted to be God.

I would recommend starting with Isaiah 14 and reading that chapter. The problem with man made theology is that it can easily distort God's word. If the church or Christian denomination you belong to doesn't preach from the Bible, I would use a high level of discernment.

We'd like to believe that all Christian pioneers are 100% faithful to the Lord, but that's not possible, and generally untrue. Ever heard the phrase wolves in sheep's clothing?

Be blessed!