# Was there a war in Heaven?

Tags: biblical-basis, heaven, war

There seems to be an idea among some Christians of a metaphysical timeline that goes something like this:

1. All the angels are created sometime before or during the 7 days of creation in Genesis.
2. Satan desires to become like God, and starts a "war in heaven"
3. Satan loses the war and is cast out of Heaven along with many other angels before or during the time Adam and Eve reside in Eden.
4. Satan, fallen and cast out of Heaven, appears in Eden in the form of a serpent to tempt Eve, and Adam.
5. Satan continues to tempt, torment, and accuse mankind, as evident in Job.
6. Satan is bound for a time when the Messiah comes into power.
7. Satan is released from bondage and wages a final war upon Heaven with his fallen angels and many nations who follow him.
8. Satan is defeated and cast into the lake of fire, which is eternal destruction.

Was there a war in Heaven for which Satan was cast out that occurred *before* the fall of man?

What Biblical sources can be cited that describe the events that led to the exile of Satan from Heaven?

Comment: Please choose one question to ask at a time, see my notes [below](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30118/was-there-a-war-in-heaven/30120#comment74555_30120).

Comment: @Wikis I removed the additional question to which you objected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikis has answered you question quite accurately since you asked for Biblical backup for any conclusions, and he has given you everything that is definitive in the Bible.

There are however; several things which are inferred, but are not set in stone. As to the time frame; if you want to call it that, for the war in heaven there are some clues which we can use to make an educated guess.

> Revelation 12:9  KJV And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: **he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him**.

In order for Satan and the rebellious angels to be cast to the into the Earth it would have to have been after:

> Genesis 1:1  KJV In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

and apparently before:

> Genesis 3:1  Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which the LORD God had made. And he said unto the woman, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not eat of every tree of the garden?

Since Satan is:

Rev 12:9  And the great dragon was cast out, ***that old serpent***, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.

This would necessitate that the war in Heaven:

> Revelation 12:7  KJV And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,

take place prior to Genesis 3:1

Comment: Nice addition, except that Job 1-2 shows Satan in heaven after the creation of man. How does that fit your answer?

Comment: @Wikis I must disagree with you since in neither incidence in Job states that those events took place in Heaven; ***Job 1:6  Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan came also among them***.   and    ***Job 2:1  Again there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the LORD, and Satan came also among them to present himself before the LORD***. And unless we consider the sons of God to mean the Angels it is more likely that this event took place on Earth.

Comment: Can any unclean thing (Satan) be in the presence of (present himself before) God?

Comment: Interesting, I've always assumed it *was* heaven. Good point!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there was / is / will be a war in heaven, as described in [Revelation 12:7-9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+12%3A7-9&version=NIVUK):

> Then war broke out in heaven. Michael and his angels fought against the dragon, and the dragon and his angels fought back. But he was not strong enough, and they lost their place in heaven. The great dragon was hurled down – that ancient snake called the devil, or Satan, who leads the whole world astray. He was hurled to the earth, and his angels with him.

But the specifics of when that might be in relation to Earth history (or even if that makes sense from a heavenly perspective) is speculation, this side of eternity.

Some of the speculation includes:

- During creation: see [Bye's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30130/62)
- During Jesus' earthly ministry: compare [Revelation 12:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+12%3A9&version=NIVUK) with [Luke 10:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2010:18)
- At some unspecified point in the future, taking the [futurist interpretation of Revelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation#Interpretations). (This interpretation implies that Satan is more active on Earth than currently, directly causing suffering to humans (see eg [Revelation 13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2013&version=NIVUK)).

To your numbered points:

1. The Bible does not specify or even hint as to when the angels were created.
2. [Isaiah 14:12-13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+14%3A12-13&version=NIVUK) is believed by many Christians to hint that Satan wanted to be like God.
3. We know about the war but not when it was, see above.
4. This story is detailed in [Genesis 3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3&version=NIVUK).
5. [Job 1-2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job+1-2&version=NIVUK).
6. See [Revelation 20:1-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+20%3A1-3&version=NIVUK). Many Christians believe in a literal 1000 year reign of Jesus on Earth during which Satan is bound (the Millennium).
7. Detailed a few verses later, [Revelation 20:7-10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+20%3A7-10&version=NIVUK).
8. See above passage.

Comment: for point #1, some people (me included) believe that Gen 1:3-4 talks about creation of angels (v3) and the fall of Satan (v4) although there is no Biblical support for this statement, just logic.

Comment: The question is specifically _was_ there a war in Heaven that resulted in the expulsion of Satan to Earth.

Comment: @Alex, I've interpreted those verses to be speaking of election, cf. Eph 1:4, Matt 5:14, John 1:4-14

Comment: @Wikis Re 2) Is there any in-text reason that we should conclude that Isaiah 14:12-13 refers specifically to Satan?

Comment: @Andrew: waaaaait: downvote? I answered the question you originally posted. You wanted to know about Biblical evidence for a war in heaven. And I detailed all of your other points. How is that not an answer? Then you added a completely different question at the end, which is a [duplicate](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/where-in-the-bible-does-it-say-that-lucifer-is-an-angel/2612#2612), *after I answered*, so of course I cannot have answered that. Choose one question to ask at a time, please.

Comment: My issue is that I asked "Was there a war in Heaven for which Satan was cast out that occurred before the fall of man?" and your answer was (I paraphrase) "there was or is or will be a war." I was intentionally specific about asking _when_ the war occur(ed/s), and if Satan's expulsion from Heaven was the result, but your answer was vague in that regard.

Comment: @Andrew, Wikis was specific in telling us that the Bible does not say when the war happened. Many Christians think it happened during or before creation of the Earth, and some probably think it is part of the end-times events.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Satan was in heaven and thrown out. The Bible clearly shows us that there were two different creations. Satan was the lord in the first creation where humans were just gatherers  (green meat). That world was destroyed, and in the second creation (from the dust) Adam and Eve started as tillers (agriculturists), and later as shepherds (Cain), and finally, after the flood (Noah) as omnivores.

Comment: Where does it clearly show this?

Comment: Eze 28:12, Jer 4:23 (The Creation Account in Genesis - Bruce K. Waltke)

Comment: Can you explain how those verses show two creations with Satan as the lord of the first?

Comment: Jer 4:30 shows an already "spoiled" Satan, and we see Satan's first arrival in Gen 3:1 as already "subtil"; contrast with Eze 28:14+. Also, if the first creation explicitly states "green meat" for all the creation, Adam and Eve were created by an omniscient God as tillers, not as gatherers of green things, most probably because the omniscient God knew they would fall and have to go independent instead of relying on God provided "green meat". And later we see them as tillers.

Answer (score -3):

Ok firstly how can anyone start a war in heaven against God,  If he is omnipotent then should he not have forseen this happening infact why would he let such a creation exist when he knew that the same creation would end up perishing for eternity?

Intrestingly Satan appears to be casual when talking with God as if this war never happened,  I would even go so far as to saying that they are friends or that Satan is not Gods Adversary.  He then makes a wager and God knowing the overall outcome allows satan to torture a family to prove a point for no reason whatsoever!

With regards to fellow Christians using Revelation lets be honest here that Book is very disputed in so much as we don’t even know that it’s the same God that John of Patamos talked about as the God of Abraham.

John also called Jesus the Bright Morning Star yet in other places we find Lucifer named the very same thing.