# Does the Bible say that the Devil was an archangel?

Tags: satan, angels

Did the Devil's expulsion from heaven occur before Jesus came to earth?

Does the bible say that the Devil was an archangel?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For your questions to work here, you'll need to ask one question at a time, and say what denomination of Christians you want an answer from. For some help on asking questions, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and read some of the other questions and answers here.

Comment: To the extent that this arises from Isa. 14:12  > Luke 10:18, [this Q&A on Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8066/3555) explains it nicely. Some of the same territory [has also been covered on this site](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2609/13677).